# MX Google Map Control Panel Error

Tags: jquery, mx-google-map

I am getting the following errors when opening an entry with an MX Google Map field type. Map is not loading in control panel. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google

```
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
```

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.mxgoogleMaps.defaults')

```
var opts = $.extend({}, $.mxgoogleMaps.defaults, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the site is running over https I had to modify the URL in the following line of code to https.

**fx.mx_google_map.php (Line 135)**

```
ee()->cp->add_to_foot('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>');
```